# Android Kotlin Foregeground Service + Notifications, Why works wrong?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

In my application, I need a foreground service that will check a certain condition every minute, and if it is correct, it triggers a notification reminder. The user determines in advance what time and day he would like to have the reminder to. Data is saved in the database. Then the service every minute checks if it has a reminder for a given hour and day and if so sends a notification. The service must work when the user uses the application, when the application runs in the background and when it is closed. Could someone tell me why this code works on one phone but not on others? So-called, if I set a reminder,  up to 20 minutes, it works (in all 3 states that I wrote about earlier), but once I set the reminder for the next days, it doesn't work anymore. I am surprised that sometimes the reminder on another phone works and sometimes it doesn't. I checked, the permission for the application to run in the background is selected in the settings. Please help.

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<application
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/pills"
            android:label="@string/nameOfApplications"
            android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service
                android:name=".ForegroundService"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**ForegroundService**

```
class ForegroundService : Service() {
    companion object {
        val CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel"
        val CHANNEL_ID_CHILD = "ForegroundServiceChannelCHILD"
        private var  isRunning = false
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val input = intent.getIntExtra("time",15)
        createNotificationChannel()
        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, Menu::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0
        )

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("MotherNotification")
            .setContentText("Message")
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .build()

        startForeground(1, notification)
        isRunning = true
        val context = this
        val intent = Intent(this, ShowAll::class.java)
        val pendingIntentNotification = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        doAsync {
            while(isRunning)
            {
                var message : String = createReminderMessage(context)

                //SystemClock.sleep(input * 10_000L)
                SystemClock.sleep(50000)
                uiThread {
                    if(isRunning && (message != "Nadszedł czas by zażyć: ")) {
                        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID_CHILD)
                            .setContentTitle("Title")
                            .setContentText(message)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntentNotification)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .build()
                        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
                            notificationManager.notify(2, notification)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }




    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        isRunning = false
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT

            )
            val serviceChannel2 = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID_CHILD,
                "Foreground Service ChannelChild ",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                //NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            )

            val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel2)
        }
    }

    fun reminderForNow(context: Context) : ArrayList<Reminder> {
        var listOfReminder : ArrayList<Reminder> = ArrayList()
        var timetoday = takeTimeNow()
        var dateToday = takeTodayDate()

        val dbHelper = SQLConector(context)
        val allRemindersList = dbHelper.getAllReminders()
        for (i: Reminder in allRemindersList) {

            if (i.reminderDate == dateToday && i.ReminderTime == timetoday) {
                var reminder = Reminder(
                    i.id,
                    i.Name,
                    i.reminderDate,
                    i.ReminderTime
                )
                listOfReminder.add(reminder)
            }
        }
        return listOfReminder
    }

    private fun createReminderMessage(p0: Context) : String{
        var message : String = "title : "
        var listOfReminders = reminderForNow(p0)
        if(listOfReminders.count() > 0){
            for (i: Reminder in listOfReminders) {
                message += i.Name + ", "
            }
        }
        return message
    }

 private fun takeTodayDate():String{
        val current = LocalDateTime.now()
        val formatDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
        var dateResult = current.format(formatDate).toString()
        return  dateResult
    }

    private fun takeTimeNow() : String{
        val current = LocalDateTime.now()
        val formatTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")
        var timeResult = current.format(formatTime).toString()
        return  timeResult

    }

}
```

**Main Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.buttonStart.setOnClickListener { startService() }
        binding.buttonStop.setOnClickListener {stopService()  }
        startService()
    }


    private fun startService() {
        val serviceIntent = Intent(this, ForegroundService::class.java)
        serviceIntent.putExtra("time", 1)

        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent)
    }

    private fun stopService() {
        val serviceIntent = Intent(this, ForegroundService::class.java)
        stopService(serviceIntent)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle tasks which require exact fire time is to use the [AlarmManagerCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/AlarmManagerCompat) class.

You can use `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(...)` method to force the alarm to start your service even when the device is in Doze mode and you will need a `BroadcastReceiver` to re-schedule the alarms if the device is rebooted.

You can find some references online on how to implement that.

Comment: I have already consulted this problem and  "work manager" was discouraged.
I am surprised that this code works fine on one phone. and not on another. due to restrictions, I don't have 3 phones to check this code.
However
Could you show me how to transform my code to get what I would like with a work manager?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I was wrong, the workmanager still doesn't have the exact time run feature (I thought they added it but currently not). AlarmManager is your only way to go.